# Warning C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary. But I return a input argument value

Tags: c++, templates

I designed a template class which can operate several kinds of strings, such as CString and std::string. I have been using it long time, and it works fine. But the "return str[i]" in "at" function led to a warning C4172, that means I return an address of local varible. But the str isn't a local varible. It should be passed from the outside.
How can I make the compile not prompt the warning?

```
template<class TSTR, typename TCHR>
    class stringOpr
    {
    public:
        typedef typename TSTR TSTRING;
        typedef typename TCHR TCHARTYPE;
        virtual const TCHARTYPE& at(const TSTRING& str, int i) const
        {
            return str[i];//Warning C4172
        }
...
};
```

[image]

Comment: Change the return type from `const TCHARTYPE&` to `TCHARTYPE`.

Comment: @Eljay, string::operator[] just returns a reference. How do I make the compiler know that the str[i] return a reference?

Comment: Now, I think the warning makes sense. If some type of string implement the operator[] really doesn't return a reference...

Comment: My at is virtual, just in case of that, I can rewrite it to fit the returning a reference.

Comment: How do you instantiate this template? What is `TSTR`?

Comment: @AnT, string, wstring, CString ... all kind of string can fit in it, as long as you implement these virtual functions, such as "at", "mid". I just did this for one algorithm to implement split, join ... for string, wstring, CString ...

Comment: @AnT, Now I give myself a satisfied answer in the below.

Comment: Well, the point is that there's NO such warning as you describe with all of these types. Only some specific `TSTR` types trigger it. So, when you ask such questions, it makes sense to specify which specific `TSTR` types triggered this warning.

Comment: @AnT, am I correct to assume that there should be a warning when `const TSTRING& str` is a temporary?

Comment: @Alexey Andronov: No, the compiler cannot know whether `str` is bound to a temporary. The warning is generated when `str[i]` returns a temporary, i.e. when `TSTR::operator[]` returns its result "by value". For example, when `TSTR` is `std::string`, the warning will not appear.

Comment: @AnT, why though? It's a template, hence during instantiation it can have this information

Comment: Um... Actually, *instantiation* is exactly when it has this information. When the user instantiates this template and this `at` member with a *specific* `TSTR` type - that's when the warning is generated. Only for those `TSTR` types that return a temporary from their `[]` operators.

Comment: @AnT, thanks for clarification, just got confused by your `No, the compiler cannot know whether str is bound to a temporary` when it actually know

Comment: @Alexey Andronov: Again, the warning is generated when the compiler instantiates the `at` method. However, the compiler does not know and does not care how this method is going to be used in the future. It does not know whether `str` will be bound to a temporary or to a non-temporary in future calls to this method. The warning is not triggered by what `str` is bound to. The warning is triggered by what the result of `str[i]` is, which is a completely different story. The latter depends on what `TSTR` is, not on what `str` is bound to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178176/discussion-between-alexey-andronov-and-ant).

Comment: @AnT, I get your point. CString::operator[] really doesn't return a reference.
 XCHAR operator[](_In_ int iChar) const
So, it prompts this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning makes sense.
If there is a MyString that the operator of it didn't return a reference.

```
class MyString
{
char operator[](int i) const;
};
```

This function will crash.
In this case, you should rewrite your "at" function to fit a returning reference.
If you really want to return a reference, do this,

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4172)    
virtual const TCHARTYPE& at(const TSTRING& str, int i) const
{
    return str[i];
#pragma warning(default : 4172)
}
```

Ignore the warning, and re-enable it after this.

/*----------------------------------------------------*/

CString::operator[] really doesn't return a reference. So I make a concession

```
virtual /*const*/ TCHARTYPE/*&*/ at(const TSTRING& str, int i) const
        {
            return str[i];
        }
```